# Reading serialized jquery data in PHP (multiple checkboxes)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(){
        var content = $(this).serialize();
        //alert(content);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'http://localhost/test/generate',
            timeout: 15000,
            data:{  content: content },
            success: function(data){
                $('.box').html(data).fadeIn(1000);
            },
            error: function(){
                $('.box').html('error').fadeIn(1000);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" value="first" name="opts[]">
<input type="checkbox" value="second" name="opts[]">
<input type="checkbox" value="third" name="opts[]">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

How do i process (or read) multiple checked checkbox's value in PHP? I tried doing `$_POST['content']` to grab the serialized data but no luck.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to send the data as JSON? A default post of the form will make your data available as `$_POST['opts']` (it will return an array). If you need to keep it as json, try `var_dump($_POST)` to see what you're getting.

Comment: He is not sending the data as JSON. The `dataType` parameter indicates the server response content type, not the request.

Comment: @Darin Ah, I haven't worked with jQuery much, (Does it show? :D) but I was referring to his serialization of the form and the `data:{  content: content }` line

Comment: @Grexis, this is not JSON. jQuery automatically serializes this javascript literal into an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request. Nothing to do with JSON. If you wanted to send JSON to the server you would specify the `contentType: 'json'` and you would JSON serialize the request: `data: JSON.stringify({ content: 'some content' })`.

Comment: @Darin I'm going to stop while, I'm (somewhat) ahead. Still, I suppose this is the best way to learn

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace:

```
data:{  content: content } // <!-- you are prefixing with content which is wrong
```

with:

```
data: content
```

Now in your PHP script you can use `$_POST['opts']` which normally should return an array.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
echo $_POST['opts'][0]. "<br />";
echo $_POST['opts'][1]. "<br />";
echo $_POST['opts'][2]. "<br />";
```

You post an array to the Server and it is available in the post variable 'opts'. Remember: Unchecked boxes dont get posted.

Answer (score 0):

The chosen answer still didn't work for me, but here is what did:

```
var checkedBoxesArr = new Array();
$("input[name='checkedBoxes']:checked").each(function() {
    checkedBoxesArr.push($(this).val());
});
var checkedBoxesStr = checkedBoxesArr.toString(); 
var dataString = $("#" + formID).serialize() + 
                  '&checkedBoxesStr=' + checkedBoxesStr;
```

[The above code goes in your javascript, before serializing the form data]
First, cycle through the checked boxes and put them into an array. 
Next, convert the array to a string.
Last, append them to the serialized form data manually - this way you can reference the string in your PHP alongside the rest of the serialized data.

This answer came partly from this post: [Send multiple checkbox data to PHP via jQuery ajax()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493531/send-multiple-checkbox-data-to-php-via-jquery-ajax)

Answer (score -2):

there are an Error in your code :

1. The url should be `url: 'http://localhost/test/generate.php'` with the extension name