# Passing multiple checkbox values to PHP in ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I have a form with a number of check boxes,I want to delete images that their checkboxes has been checked, by deleting through their id, please what will be the best way to pass both all the checked check boxes respective ids to my PHP code.

```
<button class="delete btn btn-outline-primary dropdown-toggle" style="margin-left: 10px" id="saveReorder1">Delete Multiple</button><br/>

<div id="deleteHelper" style="display:none;">
<span class="selected-txt mt-5 ml-5"                                                                                  
 style="text-align: left">1. Select the check boxes of the images you want to delete &nbsp;</span></div>
<ul class="reorder row" style="margin-left: 30px">
<form id="chk-all" class="row">
 @foreach ($images as $image)
 <input type="checkbox" name="chk" class="chk" style="display: none;"><li class="img-box" data-src="{{$image->filename}}" id="{{$image->id}}">
 <div class="img-w" data-src="{{$image->filename}}"
style="background-image: url('{{$image->filename}}')"></div>
<span style="color: #333333;position: relative;width: 100%;text-align: justify;display: inline;margin-left: 10px;">{{$image->description}} <i class="fa fa-upload"
                                                                        style="margin-left: 10px; color:#333333;"></i><i class="far fa-trash-alt del1" id="{{$image->id}}" style="margin-left: 10px; color:#333333;cursor: pointer;float:right"></i></span></li>@endforeach</form></ul>



 $('.delete').on('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            $('#deleteHelper').slideDown('slow');
            $("ul.reorder").find('.chk').fadeToggle();
            $('.chk').on('click',function(e){
             $('.delete').html('Delete Selected');
            });
            let form = $('#chk-all').serialize();
            $('.delete').attr("id", "deletes");
            $("#deletes").click(function (e) {
                if (!$("#deletes i").length) {
                    $(this).html('').prepend('deleting...').delay(1000).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
                }
                $.ajax({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    },
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "delete.php",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (h) {
                        window.location.reload();
                        //  console.log(h);
                    }
        //    $("ul.reorder").find('#chk-form')
        });
        });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send multiple checkbox data to PHP via jQuery ajax()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493531/send-multiple-checkbox-data-to-php-via-jquery-ajax)

Comment: @hungrykoala It doesn't work for me

Comment: How will i get the ids

Comment: set checkbox name as an array like in the dup and set the value of the checkbox to the id of the image.

Comment: Please add your answer below, so that I'll verify